# Rails has_many through association not updating join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :projects, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

and the migration for memberships

```
def change
  create_table :memberships do |t|
    t.belongs_to :user
    t.belongs_to :project
    t.boolean :admin
  end
end
```

In my controller, I want to create a project for the current user

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  if @project.save
    render json: @project, status: :ok
  else
    render json: { errors: @project.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name)
end
```

When `@project.save` is called, the SQL in the log:

```
INSERT INTO "projects" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-12-09 17:18:55.298566"], ["name", "Test"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-09 17:18:55.298566"]]
```

So memberships is never updated, so the project gets made but it is not associated with the current user. I think rails is supposed to do that automatically when using the relationship to build the object, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

It will work if I do

```
@project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
@project.users << current_user
```

But that feels incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't project has_many :users and not :projects?

Comment: i think you're using it the wrong way. The association is made when a membership is created since you are using the membership model for the many-to-many connection. the way you are using it, it's probably better to use a direct many-to-many using has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: I don't think that's right, a has_many, through is used when the relationship itself has attributes, which in this case, it does

Comment: Lookd like this may be a bug in rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12698

Comment: ah i didn't see that. surprised they haven't merged the fix yet